# Pine script Code to open new trade only between selected hours

Tags: pine-script

I am stuck.  Looking for pine script code segment that will let me select a start and stop hour (range) and then only initiate a New trade during those hours.  IF any one can help I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eagleslife,

// select hours of trading and 1234567 is which days of the week, so remove number depending if you want to trade over the weekend

```
TradingHour = input('0800-1700:1234567', title="Trading Hours")
```

Add the above as part of your alert condition

```
Long = (code for long parameters)

alertcondition(TradingHour and Long, title="Long Trading Alert", message="Enter trade, {{close}}")
```

Hope the above assists, if you provide some code we I could assist further.

Daniel

Comment: Thank you!  this helps. But I'd like to use the trading hours code in a Strategy to trigger trades only during specified time (as an input) . can you help?  many thanks

Comment: @Eagleslife I haven't coded Strategy before apologies.